# Make sure payable function receives the same ether amount in USD?

Tags: solidity

I want to enforce that a `public payable` function in my contract always charges $25 in ether. Is it feasible to create a function that does this? I know I might need to use an oracle but I'm not sure how to do this, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah like you mentioned you'll need to use a price oracle. I'd recommend you use an existing oracle instead of creating your own. For this you have 2 main options:

### 1 Price feed oracles

Price feed oracles are essentially contracts that store a price fed in from off-chain sources. Main options for this type of oracle would either be Chainlink or the MakerDAO price feeds. I'd recommend MakerDAO since they're likely gonna be less expensive on a per request basis. To integrate this you should check online tutorials or their documentation.

### 2 DEX spot price

With this approach you read the price from a DEX like Uniswap to see what the ETH/DAI or ETH/USDT price is to get a pretty good estimation of the price in dollars. This approach is more decentralized but is subject to flash loan attacks if you just do a simple price read. To mitigate against flash loan attacks you'll have to create some sort of price buffer or find an existing one. Read [this](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/smart-contract-integration/building-an-oracle/) to get started with using Uniswap as an oracle.

Comment: Thanks @MrClottom, I'll look into these!